# MySQL: selecting rows one batch at a time using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

What I try to do is that I have a table to keep user information (one row for each user), and I run a php script daily to fill in information I get from users. For one column say column A, if I find information I'll fill it in, otherwise I don't touch it so it remains NULL. The reason is to allow them to be updated in the next update when the information might possibly be available.

The problem is that I have too many rows to update, if I blindly SELECT all rows that's with column A as NULL then the result won't fit into memory. If I SELECT 5000 at a time, then in the next SELECT 5000 I could get the same rows that didn't get updated last time, which would be an infinite loop...

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this? I don't have ID columns so I can't just say SELECT WHERE ID > X... Is there a solution (either on the MySQL side or on the php side) without modifying the table?

Comment: so not normalised table. you want to update on what condition then ?

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G` and display it in the question body.

Comment: Is there any column that you can order by and limit?

Comment: @zod Ya so for all those rows with column A being NULL, I wanna do a search and see if I have information for that. If I do, I fill in column A of that row, otherwise I don't touch it.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Thank you for you reply, but I'm very sorry I rather not show the structure of my table as it's our production table. I understand you may not be able to help me due to that, but thank you all the same :)

Comment: @dleiftah Ya I thought of that too, but it turned out to be no... I can't think of how I can order the rows naturally based on the information that's available. Having an ID column would be so nice to solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use the LIMIT and OFFSET keywords.

```
SELECT [stuff] LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 5000;
```

LIMIT indicates the number of rows to return, and OFFSET indicates how far along the table is read from.

Comment: This is interesting, so I'll have to manually multiply the OFFSET in each loop?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can put an expression in the OFFSET, like 5000*page for instance.